# Can we make the values in pandas.pivot_table() a count of column?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

pd.pivot_table(df, index = col1, columns = col2, value = ?)

I want the values to be the count of values in col 1.The values in col 1 are all strings.
I basically want to imitate what is happening in the excel file pictured below

[image]

Id be open to using other functions than pd.pivot_table() if that would make things easier

pd.pandas(index = col1, columns = col2, values = col1)?
Im not sure how to engage this.

```
Col1    Col2
A   Red
A   Red
A   Red
A   Blue
A   Blue
A   Blue
A   Blue
A   Blue
B   Blue
B   Blue
C   Blue
C   Blue
C   Blue
C   Blue
C   Orange
C   Orange
A   Orange
A   Orange
A   Orange
A   Orange
A   Red
A   Red
A   Red
A   Red
A   Red
B   Red
B   Green
B   Green
C   Green
C   Green
C   Green
```

Would it be possible to do something like this
[image]

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A   Red Cheetah
A   Red Cheetah
A   Red Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
B   Blue    Cheetah
B   Blue    Cheetah
C   Blue    Cheetah
C   Blue    Cheetah
C   Blue    Lion
C   Blue    Lion
C   Orange  Lion
C   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Red Lion
A   Red Lion
A   Red Bear
A   Red Bear
A   Red Bear
B   Red Bear
B   Green   Bear
B   Green   Bear
C   Green   Bear
C   Green   Bear
C   Green   Bear
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample data in text form? So we can copy and paste it...

Comment: it won't let me add it as a table

Comment: Don't put the data as a comment. Edit your question and put it there (with correct formatting - Use Ctrl+K to format the text).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab). To make the total columns use `.sum()` (with proper `axis=`)

```py
x = pd.crosstab(df.Col1, df.Col2)
x["Grand Total"] = x.sum(axis=1)
x = pd.concat([x, x.sum().to_frame().rename(columns={0: "Grand Total"}).T])
x.columns.name, x.index.name = None, None

print(x.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Blue | Green | Orange | Red | Grand Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 0 | 4 | 8 | 17 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| C | 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 9 |
| Grand Total | 11 | 5 | 6 | 9 | 31 |

Comment: Hey I added a follow-up question. Would be much appreciated if you could help out with that :)

Comment: @AhmedTawakol I recommend to open a new question here on stack overflow where you put your input/output data (in text form). I'll try to look at it.